# Why Apache POI autoSizeColumn does not work in Websphere9 on unix?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have been looking for ways to resolve this issue I faced while auto sizing the columns according the content in it. ***Excel file is created without any issue when deployed application locally on windows***. I am getting exception after deploying the application on Unix box. I found that `autoSizeColumn()` method behind the exception. Below is the code after I added all the data to excel, which throws the exception.

```
for (int colNum= 0; colNum <= 14; colNum++)
{
mySheet.autoSizeColumn(colNum);
}
```

Exception: 
`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
at sun.font.CompositeFont.getMapper(CompositeFont.java:410) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
        at sun.font.CompositeFont.canDisplay(CompositeFont.java:436) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
        at java.awt.Font.canDisplayUpTo(Font.java:2074) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
        at java.awt.font.TextLayout.singleFont(TextLayout.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
        at java.awt.font.TextLayout.<init>(TextLayout.java:542) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
        at org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getColumnWidth(SheetUtil.java:206) ~[poi-3.8.jar:3.8]
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(HSSFSheet.java:1854) ~[poi-3.8.jar:3.8]
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(HSSFSheet.java:1837) ~[poi-3.8.jar:3.8]`

I tried following after searching it on internet:
 1.Setting the JVM argument `-Djava.awt.headless=true`
 2. Made sure that Arial font is available in `java\jre\lib\fonts`

which did not help to resolve the issue.

Setup:
1. Websphere 9
2. poi3.8.jar

Comment: Please include the first line of the Exception Message too, not just the stacktrace.

Comment: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0`

Comment: At first, this seems to be an `OpenJDK` only problem. The `SheetUtil.getColumnWidth` needs a `Font` for calculating the width of the cell content. The getting this `Font` fails here. Multiple similiar erros can be found using search keys `sun.font.CompositeFont ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with the package `xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 xorg-x11-font-utils` after uninstalling it, updated font.properties file with the fonts added to JAVA. Thank you everyone.